# Hvac fuse blowing on furnace board

Tags: hvac

A 5 amp fuse keeps popping at startup on my tempstar furnace,had a problem a couple weeks ago and put fuse in and worked fine.Now it blows instantly.

Comment: I don't think anyone here will be able to help. You will probably need to look over the system completely or call in a technician. You likely have a short somewhere though, I would start by checking each wire near whatever was fixed a couple weeks ago.

Comment: We would need the model # to start with and maybe a bit more info about your system is it heating or cooling if there is a electrical print inside the cover a photo of that and the control board. Sometimes these are easy but we need the info to even take a guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op has not updated the question so it can’t be answered.